# PowerShell inspect Task Scheduler job history and report issues

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to write a PowerShell script to look at a server's task scheduler logs for a specific task. I want to know if there are any errors or anything out of the ordinary.

Typically I see event IDs `107`, `100`, `129`, `200`, `201`, and `102` when the jobs run successfully. I only want to know when something else happens such as an error, warning, etc.

Ultimately, I want to look for event IDs that are not any of the above, for a task named "`Batch001`". If any other event IDs occur, then send me an email.

- I have the email sending PowerShell code working fine—if run just as a
  section. However I need to figure out the searching, filtering, and then
  triggering of the email code.

My script below looks at the logs for a specific task and appends the corresponding full set of events from the last 24 hours to a text file—kind of an audit log. This part is also working. If there is an issue contacting the server, then it should write a message to an error text file and emails that content to me via Office 365.

**I cannot get this logic to trigger the email on warnings.** I tried testing this by emulating a failed/error/warning job by starting a batch job, and while it's running, have the schedule try to start another one. This causes a warning that it cannot launch the task because there is another instance running (`code 322`). I need this captured and emailed but I can't get it to work.

### My PowerShell Script

```
Start-Transcript -Path "C:\BatchLogs\BatchTranscripts.txt"
$task_name = "Batch001"
$file = "C:\BatchLogs\Batch001.txt"
$file_path = Test-Path $file 
$pc = $_

#If file hasn't been created, create it
If ($file_path -ne $true){
    New-Item C:\BatchLogs\Batch001.txt
}
#Filter xml to pull task scheduler events
 try {
  invoke-command -ComputerName "servername.domain" -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock {
   try {
    $events = @(
     Get-WinEvent  -FilterXml @'
     <QueryList>
      <Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">
       <Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">
        *[EventData/Data[@Name='TaskName']='\Batch001'] and *[System[TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 86400000]]]
       </Select>
      </Query>
     </QueryList>
'@  -ErrorAction Stop
   ) 
   } 
   catch {
     Write-Warning -Message "Failed to query $($env:computername) because $($_.Exception.Message)" *> "C:\BatchLogs\errors.txt" 
     Get-Content -Path "C:\BatchLogs\errors.txt" | Add-Content -Path "C:\BatchLogs\Batch001.txt"
     
     [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
     $EmailTo = "me@domain.com"
     $EmailFrom = "me@domain.com"
     $Subject = "Batch001 Failure"
     $Body = Get-Content -Path "C:\BatchLogs\errors.txt"
     $SMTPServer = "smtp.office365.com"
     $SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
     $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
     $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
     $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("me@domain.com", "Password123");
     $SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
   }
   if ($events) {
    $events | Select MachineName,TimeCreated,Id,TaskDisplayName |  Out-File -Append C:\BatchLogs\Batch001.txt 
   }
  } # end of scriptblock
 } catch {
  Write-Warning -Message "Failed to contact $pc because $($_.Exception.Message)" *> "C:\BatchLogs\errors.txt"
  Get-Content -Path "C:\BatchLogs\errors.txt" | Add-Content -Path "C:\BatchLogs\Batch001.txt"
  
  [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
  $EmailTo = "me@domain.com"
  $EmailFrom = "me@domain.com"
  $Subject = "Batch001 Failure"
  $Body = Get-Content -Path "C:\BatchLogs\errors.txt"
  $SMTPServer = "smtp.office365.com"
  $SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
  $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
  $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
  $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("me@domain.com", "Password123");
  $SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
 
 } 

 Stop-Transcript
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Potential helpful/clarifying PowerShell code

**Firstly, you did a terrific job** piecing the logic together to get you nearly exactly what you needed, so great job there. Since you are PowerShell savvy, the below logic should help you solidify your solution 100% for your preferred solution.

#### Adjustments

Put the non-error/warning event id numerical values in the `$notin` array which should not trigger any email warning or error notifications. I purposely left out `100` so I could test sending an email on that event id.

Use the `-ArgumentList` parameter of the `Invoke-Command` command and use `$jobName` as the value it uses for the argument to pass (i.e. `-ArgumentList $jobName`).

In the `-FilterXml`:

- use `"Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler"` for the `Path=` value and omit the proceeding `/Operational` value (i.e. `<Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler">`).
- pass in the `$($args[0])` as the `TaskName` too (i.e. `*[EventData/Data[@Name='TaskName']='\$($args[0])']`).

Return the `$events` inside the `Invoke-Command` scriptblock (i.e.`Return $events`).  Set the `Invoke-Command` output as the `$events` variable (i.e. `$events = Invoke-Command`).

Wrap the email sending logic in a [function](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-functions.html) just once so you can call it to execute multiple times as needed without repeating the same code.

Pipe the `$events` variable array objects over to a `ForEach-Object` loop, but only output the events for id numbers that are not in the `$notin` array objects. Pipe those over to [`Format-List`](https://ss64.com/ps/format-list.html) and save the entire loop as the `$ebody` variable.

If it's true that `$ebody` contains event data event ids that are not in the `$notin` array values, call the `email` function. Within the `email` function, the message `$body` variable will be the `$ebody` piped over to `Out-String` (i.e. `$Body = $ebody | Out-String`) so the necessary data is in the body of the email.

### PowerShell

```
$notin = 102, 107, 129, 200, 201;
$jobName = "Batch001";

$events = Invoke-Command -ComputerName "servername.domain" -ScriptBlock {

$events = @(
 Get-WinEvent  -FilterXml @"
 <QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler">
   <Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">
    *[EventData/Data[@Name='TaskName']='\$($args[0])'] and *[System[TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 86400000]]]
   </Select>
  </Query>
 </QueryList>
"@  -ErrorAction Stop
);
Return $events;

} -ArgumentList $jobName;

Function email (){
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;
    $EmailTo = "me@domain.com";
    $EmailFrom = "me@domain.com";
    $Subject = "$jobName Failure";
    $Body = $ebody | Out-String;
    $SMTPServer = "smtp.office365.com"
    $SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
    $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
    $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
    $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("me@domain.com", "Password123");
    $SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
    };
$ebody = @();
$ebody = $events | % { If ($_.id -notin $notin) {$_ | FL } }

If($ebody){email};
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Invoke-Command](https://ss64.com/ps/invoke-command.html)

  > `-ArgumentList Object[]`
  >
  > Set local variables in the command.
  > The variables in the command are replaced by these values before the command is run on
  > the remote computer. Enter the values in a comma-separated list.
  > Values are associated with variables in the order that they are listed. The alias for ArgumentList is "Args".
- [PowerShell Functions](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-functions.html)

  > At its most basic a function is simply the function keyword followed
  > by a name for the function, then some code inside a pair of curly
  > braces.
  >
  > ```
  > function Add-Numbers {  $args[0] + $args[1] }
  >
  > PS C:\> Add-Numbers 5 10 
  > 15
  > ```
- [about_Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.2)
- [PowerShell Operators $( ) @( ) :: &](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [About Comparison Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6)

  > `-notin` - value is not in a collection
- [About Assignment Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators?view=powershell-6)
- [Format-List](https://ss64.com/ps/format-list.html)

  > Standard Aliases for Format-List: `fl`
- [Out-String](https://ss64.com/ps/out-string.html)

Comment: @DawgFather .... I believe with this logic, you will not need the audit file or the `Get-Content`, and it will send you only the event id detail for those event ids that are not in the `$notin` array variable, and right in the body of the email message. The detail in the body should show you all the necessary detail of the warnings/errors along with the name of the computer in the `PSComputerName : ` field. Adjust accordingly for fit more precisely for your needs, but hopefully this gives you the nudge and other resources you need to solidify the solution you seek. Happy to help further too!

Comment: Thank you for these comments and tips...that was perfect. I ended up adding a couple extra pieces since there were some errors if there were no events for the prior 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the code assistance...this was great and I added a try/catch in order to handle an error that pops up if there are no events for the prior 24 hours.

Here is the final sanitized code that is working for me:

```
Start-Transcript -Path "C:\LogPath\TranscriptName.txt"

$jobName = "NameOfTask";
$Date = Get-Date;

$file = "C:\Daily_Batch_Log_Files\$jobName.txt"
$file_path = Test-Path $file 
$pc = $_

#If file hasn't been created, create it
If ($file_path -ne $true){
    New-Item C:\LogPath\$jobName.txt
}


#Filter xml to pull task scheduler events

#Task scheduler common event IDs to ignore (treat as good/success)
$notin = 100, 102, 107, 110, 129, 140, 200, 201;

try {

#Command to connect to remote Server (if needed)
#$events = Invoke-Command -ComputerName "servername.domain" -ScriptBlock {

#Command to execute locally
$events = Invoke-Command  -ScriptBlock {

#Pulls task scheduler, only events with the job (task's) name for events in the last 24 hours
$events = @(
 Get-WinEvent  -FilterXml @"
 <QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler">
   <Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">
    *[EventData/Data[@Name='TaskName']='\$($args[0])'] and *[System[TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 86400000]]]
   </Select>
  </Query>
 </QueryList>
"@  -ErrorAction Stop
);
Return $events;

} -ArgumentList $jobName;
}

catch {
    Write-Warning -Message "Failed to query $($env:computername) because $($_.Exception.Message)" *> "C:\LogPath\errors.txt" 
    #If events exist from last 24 hours for this task, append the text (log) file with those events
}

   if ($events) {
    Add-Content C:\LogPath\$jobName.txt "As of $Date :" #-Encoding UTF8
    $events | Select MachineName,TimeCreated,Id,TaskDisplayName |  Out-File -Append C:\LogPath\$jobName.txt #-Encoding UTF8
   }else {
       Add-Content C:\LogPath\$jobName.txt "No files found for last 24 hours as of $Date `r" -Encoding UTF8
   }

#Email function to email us but only email if there are tasks with codes other than the common success ones - only send an email if something is out of the ordinary   
Function email (){
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;
    $EmailTo = "m3@domain.com";
    $EmailFrom = "me@domain.com";
    $Subject = "$jobName Failure";
    $Body = $ebody | Out-String;
    $SMTPServer = "smtp.office365.com"
    $SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
    $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
    $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
    $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("me@domain.com", "Password123");
    $SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
    };
$ebody = @();
$ebody = $events | % { If ($_.id -notin $notin) {$_ | FL } }

If($ebody){email};

Stop-Transcript
```